# I can't seem to view my transaction history?

Tags: php

Please help :(

```
<?php
include 'dbFunctions.php';
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
?>

<table>
    <td>
        <b><label for="billinghistory">Billing History:</b></label>
        <select name="billing_history"
```

The following codes can't seem to print my transaction history, I am not sure if I have chosen the correct fields.

```
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT * from billinghistory";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
        $billing_name = $row3['billing_name'];
        $billing_name_id = $row3['billing_name_id'];
?>

            <option value="<?php echo $billing_name; ?> "><?php echo $billing_name ;?></option>
        </select>     
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: print number of records returned from your query using `mysqli_num_rows` function

Comment: When you debug this code, what *does* happen?  Are you seeing the values you expect?  Is the execution path following what you expect?  Are there any errors from PHP or from the database?  We can't debug this for you.

Comment: Offtopic, but you have a small error here: `<b><label for="billinghistory">Billing History:</b></label>`. It should be `<b><label for="billinghistory">Billing History:</label></b>` or `<label for="billinghistory"><b>Billing History:</b></label>`

Comment: Do you have access to the database? there you should see the names... Also offtopic: for of label should correspond to the name of the element. In the label there is no '_' but in the select there is...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```